# Go and Typeahead js integration

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, go, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to integrate typeahead.js with my Go program. It doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I have so far:

Directory Structure:

```
/hello/
  public/
    js/
      countries.json
      form.js
      typeahead.min.js

  templates/
    form.html

  hello.go
```

countries.json:

```
["Andorra","United Arab Emirates","Afghanistan","Antigua and Barbuda","Anguilla"]
```

form.js

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
       url: 'hello/public/js/countries.json',
       filter: function(list) {
       return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
       }
    }
});
countries.initialize();

$('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
   name: 'countries',
   displayKey: 'name',
   source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

typeahead.min.js:

The contents from `http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.min.js`

form.html

```
<html>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="[absolute path to]/hello/public/js/form.js"></script>
  <script src="[absolute path to]/hello/public/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>

  <body>            
    <form method="post" action="/join" id="loginForm">

        <div id="prefetch">
          <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Join</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

File server in hello.go:

http.Handle("/public/js/", http.StripPrefix("/public/js", http.FileServer(http.Dir(filepath.Join(cwd, "/github.com/hello/hello/public/js")))))

Error in console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
`typeahead.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I've referenced:

http://runnable.com/UlXgeluakNULAAAv/create-an-autocomplete-input-box-with-typeahead-js-for-jquery-and-javascript
http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead/

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I can see the form display and it seems like bootstrap and jquery are being imported from the CDN but there is no drop down auto complete suggestions.

I'll really appreciate help!! Or let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your URL be `/public/js/countries.json`? Also do you get any kind of error in the developer console?

Comment: ah yea, I've updated the post with the errors.

Comment: @lander when I changed the URL to /public/js/countries.json I had these extra errors:  Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/[absolute path to]/hello/public/js/form.js".
localhost/:11 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/[absolute path to]/hello/public/js/typeahead.min.js".

Comment: actually its the same either way I write it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting about "<" in typeahead.min.js:1 sounds like your backend is returning html instead of javascript.

You might want to check your routes.

You didn't show hello.go, so this is just a guess, but I think the path in html should be "/js/...", not an absolute path.

Comment: If you start the service with something like http.FileServer(http.Dir("public")), the html should refer to "/js" , not "/public/js".

Comment: I started the service with http.FileServer(http.Dir("[absolute path to]/public/js")). Will that make a difference?

Comment: I set the http header to Content-type: application/javascript and that resolved the error. But I now only see the html code on the web page.

Comment: Take this for example:


http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer


If the "public" folder has a index.html, it will be served on the top level. HTML is rendered in the browser, and it will not have access anywhere else than the public folder.


All the browser sees is the folder, starting from "/". So your "[ABSOLUTE_PATH]/project/public/js/script.js" should be "/js/script.js" in the HTML file.

Comment: alright, I've changed it them to /js/script.js already but I still see HTML code on the page.

Comment: I think you set the content type to javascript for all server files, that would make the browser show the html file as plain-text and not include the .js file, thus getting rid of the error.

Comment: ahh what should I do then??